# ActionScript 2 load another SWF that loads other files - relative path/url problem

Tags: actionscript-2

Few facts first:
 1. I can only use ActionScript 2.
 2. All files are within the same domain (i.e "http://www.example.com").

I have a loader SWF which acts as a selection tool ("**auto_magic.swf**") **located at "/"** in the website (the root folder).
A User selects the tool he needs (it's a mechanical diagnostic system) and the main movie loads it (currently I use loadMovie() - suggest else if needed).
That tool is located at "**/tools/[tools_name]/tool_main.swf**".

Now, the "tool_main.swf" is loading just fine.
The problem is that **"tool_main.swf" needs to load other files located in its folder**, so for example it tries to load "config.xml", BUT Flash isn't looking for "config.xml" in the tool's dedicated folder - instead it's looking for this file at the root folder "/" where "auto_magic.swf" is located, probably because the movie's main swf is coming from there.

To make it even worst I cannot modify the tool's SWF ("tool_main.swf") because it's coming from a third party.

Is there any solution? As far as I see this I need one of these solutions;
 **1.** Be able to **set the base url of the loaded swf**.
 **2.** **Change** the whole **movie's base url at run-time** because it needs to load several tools from different folders.

Trying to solve this for several good hours. Help will be highly appriciated!

Comment: Only four views uh - so depressing. If you too HATE Flash please upvote (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

relative paths are always relative to where the main swf exists. so as your load chain expands, '/' always refers to the location of the Main.swf.

in AS2, you can inspect a swfs `_url` property to determine its fully qualified url location, and determine its parent folder.

In the AS2 child swf, you can use this:

```
var myfolder = this._url.slice(0, this._url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

and then use that to load in further assets relative to itself.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying at least, and yes, this is the closest one can get with Flash.